# Using NOLOCK in UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, nolock

Using NOLOCK in UPDATE statement:

Both the below queries are working fine.

```
UPDATE ml
SET CreationUserId = 'system'
FROM mst_login AS ml WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE LoginId = 300


UPDATE mst_login
SET CreationUserId = 'system'
FROM mst_login WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE LoginId = 300
```

What is the difference (in terms of performance) between these 2 ways of using NOLOCK in update statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference.  One is just using a table alias.